# XML Schema(XSD): Is it possible to create a rule/relation for an element based on another element?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have 2 elements:

1. Total number of connections
2. Connections per second.

I would like to enforce the following rules:

- Connections per second should be less than or equal to total connections.
- Default value of connections per second should be equal to total connections

Currently I have total connections as following:

```
<xs:simpleType name="TotalConnections" use="optional" default=1> 
    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger"> 
        <xs:minExclusive value="0" />
         <xs:maxInclusive value="8000"/> 
    </xs:restriction> 
</xs:simpleType>
```

How do I link total connections with cps in my schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressing the constraint is not possible with XSD 1.0; it can be done in XSD 1.1 using assertions.

```
<xs:assert test="ConnectionsPerSecond le TotalConnections"/>
```

Even with XSD 1.1 it's not possible to define default values that are computed rather than constant.